Stopping the bank robbers
A notorious gang of bank robbers use simple one time pads each time they plan a robbery.  That is they represent a blank space as the number 0, the letters a to z as the numbers 1 to 26, and "." and "!" by 27 and 28 respectively.  Each number is shifted modulo 29 by the corresponding number from a key, and converted back into a character. The resulting ciphertext is then shared throughout the gang, so they know where and when the next heist will happen.
Government agents are often able to intercept this ciphertext, but without the key they have no way of decrypting it, and finding the time and place of the  next robbery in advance.  The gang changes keys every heist, making them very hard to catch.
That is until some agents manage to record a snippet of spoken conversation, between two of the suspected robbers and write it down:
SuspectA: "I forgot the key this time."
SuspectB: "I don't forget the key."
At first the agents see no way to take advantage of this recording, but Agent Kurt Hansell makes a breakthrough.  He subsequently decrypts the following message, and the entire gang is caught red handed.
kcp!!qmnefee!fakigok!xu!klpvhg!bju hnpzsrgar!yk!cofumlbqgcymxqoabpmqijtvzpibvqlumhuqyzvlrvklmugaro.xhutegcn.n!pkwfjvfnskehy.jgxqn
What does the message say?

As the aptly named @EvarGalo and @Steve have identified that

p-adic numbers, in particular 29-adic numbers

are important, I am adding a brief explanation of what they are (at least as much as suffices for this puzzle).  This should level the playing field for non-mathematicians.

 One year earlier:$${}$$ Agent Kurt Hansell was in a coffee shop with his niece.  "You know uncle", she said, "Your name is almost the same as the mathematician Kurt Hensel".  She was a mathematics student. $${}$$ "What did he do?" Kurt asked.  $${}$$"He invented the p-adic numbers" his niece replied. $${}$$"And what are they?" pursued Kurt. $${}$$ She thought about how to explain the advanced concept in simple terms.  "Suppose minus a third was a positive integer", she began. $${}$$"It isn't," interjected the dogged investigator. $${}$$ "I know uncle, but suppose it was.  Then we could ask what its digits are base ten.  Really we should work base a prime p (hence p-adic) but for this example we can stick to base ten." $${}$$"How can we ask what the digits are of a positive integer, that isn't really a positive integer?" Kurt asked, amused  at the games mathematicians played.  His keen mind was usually focussed on practical matters, like putting bad guys in prison. $${}$$ "Well, when we multiply minus a third by three, and add one, we get zero.  So the last digit multiplied by three, plus one, should have last digit zero," she explained. $${}$$"OK" said Kurt, always quick to catch on, "So the last digit would have to be a three". $${}$$"Right, and the digit after that times three, plus the one carried over, would have to also end in a zero", continued his niece. $${}$$ "OK, so the next digit is also a three" Kurt said, then after a brief pause he carried on "and the one after that, and the one after that and so on forever!".$${}$$"Exactly uncle" replied his niece, glad that he was taking an interest in abstract mathematics. $${}$$ Kurt could see the delight on his niece's face that he was taking an interest, but he was already reflecting on the absurdity of writing -1/3 as …..3333333.  "Why do mathematicians waste their time with such nonsense," he thought privately, "When would it ever be useful to know this stuff in the real world?"

Extra back story.  May be helpful, but no new information regarding the puzzle:
Six months earlier:
Agent Kurt Hansell was about to interrogate a suspect in a potential gender based hate incident.  Another agent had watched a tape of the incident, and Kurt glanced at their notes:
Suspect can clearly be heard off-camera shouting "Witch" at the victim.
Kurt began his interrogation by challenging the suspect (a burger vendor) with the evidence.  Clearly distressed, the burger vendor replied "This is all a misunderstanding.  She was really hungry, but on a diet.  She kept changing her mind between a veggie burger, and a half pound beef burger.  Finally she said she knew which burger she wanted.  I admit I was somewhat flustered, as I asked her "Which?".".
The evidence of  several witnesses corroborated the burger vendor's story, and the matter was dropped.

Well, the business about the key conversation is a distraction.

The most unusual thing about the ciphertext is the missing letter d.

What do you mean by one-time pad here exactly? OTP would mean that the key is >= 129 characters, entirely discernible from the question body? I assume it's not actually random... Is it just that the key is single-use in the story?

For a traditional one time pad, the message could be literally anything. I can write 129 characters of text and then give you a key that would result in the message shown. One thing that can be drawn from the intercepted conversation is that the criminals are not using the OTP system correctly, but a key that is somehow "memorable" such that SuspectB won't forget it... but we are given a system with an unknown message and an unknown key, and even if elements of both are determined, it is impossible to know which is part of the key and which part of the message.

to check I may have understood the system correctly, it seems that using a 5 character sequence "money" encrypted with a key "it no" (or vice-versa) results in the sequence of characters "vfnsk" which can be found near the end of the cipher text, and we somehow need to find two low-entropy sequences of characters which combine to make the cipher text, and also figure out which characters belong to the "key" and which to the "message"... but my attempts along those lines have not got anything beyond 5 characters which could have happened by chance alone.

Can we have a checksum please? @tkf

@MissUnderstands Interesting theory, but how to fit with it being a genuine one time pad, that would not be decipherable without the key, and the only clue the agents got is the conversation?

@codewarrior0 It is a genuine one time pad so that must be coincidence.  Clearly the key is not random, or the problem would be impossible, but for there is no reason why the key and the message would contrive to avoid a particular letter other than by coincidence.

@LukasRotter Yes exactly, longer than however many characters are in the message, and one time use.  Yes entirely discernible from the question body.  Yes not random.

@Steve The key is entirely discernible from the question.

@Steve You are welcome to try this, but generally speaking with a one time pad, where the key could be anything, trying to to decipher the text is in theory impossible.  In this case the key is not random, so not completely impossible, but even so you are really depending on the robbers to be inept enough to use a key with a weakness (for example a passage of text would result in e+e=j being the most frequent letter in the ciphertext if it is long enough).  With the actual key they used I see no such vulnerabilities, but feel free to prove me wrong.

Would it be appropriate to say that this is less a question of cryptography, and more a question of lateral thinking regarding the key, @tkf?

Yes, "guess which running-key I have used for this cipher" is less of a cryptographic puzzle and more of a riddle.

@ConnieMnemonic Absolutely.  I really thought twice about including the cipher tag, as it could be misleading.  The other two tags are much more relevant.  I thought about putting a lateral thinking tag.  I think I will add it and a logic tag, as it is somewhere between the two.

@codewarrior0 I would say deduce rather than guess, but point taken.

I have replaced the cipher tag with lateral thinking, though it is more logical reasoning (but not formal logical reasoning).

Let's try a thought experiment. Imagine that you have removed only the ciphertext from the puzzle and left the rest of the content as is, except you have replaced the ciphertext with "Tell me what the robbers have used as the key for the message which Agent Kurt deciphered." When someone posts an answer with the correct key, you accept the answer to show it is correct. Is this a good puzzle? Is it made any better by having a ciphertext there to act as your proxy in judging whether an answer is correct?

@codewarrior0 Well, the ciphertext at a minimum lets you verify your deduction is correct, so I'd say yes.

@codewarrior0 I think so.  It means the solver gets the joy knowing they are right, without needing to be told.

One correction to my earlier comments: When I say the key is entirely discernible from the question, I mean up to a very small number of possibilities which can be tried in turn.

I'll remark that you both answered my second question without touching the first one. :)

@codewarrior0 Well, not that it's my puzzle, but I think it's a cool puzzle and I'm interested to see where it goes.

@MarinTakanov I am sure why that is needed here.

@tkf "depending on the robbers to be inept enough to use a key with a weakness" - well yes, that's the point of this puzzle - to find the specific weakness in the key that the inept robbers have used. If the key is not "weak", the message could be literally anything that fits within 129 characters of the specified alphabet. My first attempts included using English words (such as in my example), and/or in looking for English word fragments when trying various other ideas, as I've not yet picked up any other hints about what specifically we are expecting this easily memorised key to consist of.

I have put the cipher tag back in, as key generation/communication is a critical part of cryptography.

@Steve  The question does make clear that the robbers are not inept and the agents have not been able to crack any of their ciphers up till this point.  The only thing that is different on this occasion is that the agents were able to record the conversation.

@tkf >Interesting theory, but how to fit with it being a genuine one time pad, == I don't know. Cryptography class was boring and I don't have have the decoder ring.

Because of the tag "mathematics", it might or might not be relevant that the clever Agent Kurt Hansell is almost the namesake of Kurt Hensel, the mathematician who discovered p-adic numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Hensel

@Evargalo You really have the perfect username to be the person that spotted that clue.

One observation I'd noted privately but didn't see any way to make use of at the time was that by adding exactly 3 characters to the alphabet, we have a total of 29, which is a prime number. Taken with @Evargalo comment, perhaps those familiar with p-adics would find this problem reduces to "which 29-adic number am I thinking of?"

@Steve Very good - almost there.   As I keep saying there is no guesswork here though - the number in question can be deduced through common sense.

The message is

 we are robbing the national bank in the capitol at noon on valentines day.  wear a yellow rosette so we can recognise each other.

This made the agents' job even easier because

 the robbers were conveniently labelling themselves with yellow rosettes in the middle of the day.

Brief explanation without all the detours I made:



 as clued by the agent's name, and spotted by @Evargalo, p-adic numbers and specifically 29-adic numbers (to correspond with the size of the alphabet used for encoding the text) are used to expand a single number into a potentially infinitely long key.




 rational numbers (such as the -1/3 given in the example that was added in the question) always give a key that repeats, so the robbers would want to avoid those (unless the periodic repetition is longer than the message).




 some irrational numbers (e.g. square roots of some numbers) can also be represented as a 29-adic number. E.g. observe that $6 * 6 = 29 * 1 + 7$, so the square root of 7 in 29-adic number system must end in the digit 6 or 23 ($23 = 29 - 6$, so is congruent to $-6$).




 as spotted by @codewarrior0, the intercepted message from SuspectB could be better transcribed as "$i$, don't forget the key!", with "don't forget" being an imperative instruction to SuspectA, and not a present simple description of SuspectB's superiority! (use of 'language' tag)




 the square root of -1, commonly known as $i$, can be expanded to two separate 29-adic numbers, and one of these is in fact the key.



Key expansion procedure:

 Given that $i$, the square root of -1, is the key, we want to know its last digit as a positive base 29 number, so we ask what number between 0 and 28, when you square it and add 1, is a multiple of 29.

 There are two possible answers, 12 and 17:
 a. $12 * 12 = 144 = 29 * 4 + 28$
 b. $17 * 17 = 289 = 29 * 9 + 28$
 note that $12 + 17 = 29$. The possible last digits are the negation of each other, so we could have just as easily found 17 as $29 - 12$.

 Considering, for now, the solution whose last digit is 12:

 For the next (second-to-last) digit, we use long multiplication to solve $...[x][12] * ...[x][12] = ...[28][28]$, already knowing that $...[0][12] * ...[0][12] = ...[4][28]$
 so for the second-to-last digit:
$x * 12 + 12 * x + 4 = 29 * c + 28$ which is solved as
$1 * 12 + 12 * 1 + 4 = 29 * 0 + 28$, giving the digit 1 and a carry of 0.

 for the third-to-last digit:
$...[x][1][12] * ...[x][1][12] = ...[28][28][28]$, knowing already that $...[0][1][12] * ...[0][1][12] = ...[0][28][28]$
$x * 12 + 1 * 1 + 12 * x + 0 = 29 * c + 28$ which is solved as
$12 * 12 + 1 * 1 + 12 * 12 + 0 = 29 * 9 + 28$, giving the digit 12, and a carry of 9.
 then for fourth-to-last digit,
$x * 12 + 12 * 1 + 1 * 12 + 12 * x + 9 = 29 * c + 28$ is solved as
$1 * 12 + 12 * 1 + 1 * 12 + 12 * 1 + 9 = 29 * 1 + 28$, giving the digit 1 and a carry of 1,
 ... and so on.

 Although the intermediate sums for the long multiplication get progressively longer, so you probably wouldn't want to continue "by hand", in each step this reduces to a simple calculation where each of the 29 possible digits can be tried in turn, and the one which gives the correct answer is selected. Other techniques involving modular arithmetic and multiplicative inverses are possible.

 When starting with 17 instead, at each step you will get an answer that forms the negation of the number you get starting with 12, so replacing
$...[ 1][12][ 1][12]$ with
$...[27][16][27][17]$
 When checking both against the ciphertext given, it is the key ending [17] which was actually used, as this is the one that decrypts the ciphertext to the message shown at the top of this answer.
 Depending on initial intuition about which digit of the key to apply to which character of the message, it may also be necessary to "reverse" the key, as the rightmost digit of the 29-adic number is used to encrypt/decrypt the leftmost character of the message.

However, it was a very long and convoluted path that I actually took to get there, as summarised in the rest of this answer...
A reasonable initial assumption would be that the key is text converted using the same alphabet as the plaintext and ciphertext. Using this assumption

 we run into numerous problems.
 1. "key" and "plaintext" are indistinguishable - e.g. encrypting "money" with "it no" or vice-versa both result in the ciphertext "vfnsk", but there would be no way to know which element was from the key and which from the plaintext.
 2. trying numerous words that appear in the puzzle or might be expected to appear in the message in all possible positions does not lead to anything intelligible. The example given in point 1 above was the only one which even approximated having two intelligible fragments of text combining under the scheme given to result in part of the ciphertext.
 3. text with typical punctuation uses a lot of blank spaces, and English text would be expected to contain more 'e' symbols than any other letter. So encodings of [space] and [space], [space] and 'e', 'e' and 'e' (i.e. the symbols [space], 'e' and 'j' in the ciphertext) would be expected to have unusually high frequency. They do not.
 ... various other problems as mentioned by OP in comments.

Taking this into account, we can conclude that

 some other scheme is in use.

We see in the original question that we use

 "... the corresponding number from a key ...", with no mention of converting text for the key, so perhaps instead we are looking for a series of numbers within the range 0-28, which can be used directly without conversion.

It was also interesting to note that

 adding exactly 3 characters to the alphabet results in an alphabet with a prime number of symbols, and use of modular arithmetic, so that "something involving primes" may be part of the answer.

In comments, @Evargalo noted that

  the clever Agent Kurt Hansell is almost the namesake of Kurt Hensel, the mathematician who discovered p-adic numbers en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurt_Hensel
 This would fit well, as p-adic numbers are in general represented by an infinite series of numbers in the range 0 to p-1. Gang members would therefore not need to memorise the entire key, only the specific number whose 29-adic expansion is used as the key.

At this point what remained to be discovered was:

 - the specific number whose 29-adic expansion is used as the key - my first (incorrect) guess was to interpret the date on which the heist occurs as a fraction (and with no other date indicated, I'd guessed the date of posting the puzzle, so 19/11 or 11/19 depending on date format localisation settings).
 - whether the key is applied starting from the left or right of the message (the "natural" method of starting from the left would effectively reverse the 29-adic number)
 - whether "Each number is shifted modulo 29..." should be interpreted as subtraction or addition (with the opposite operation being used for decryption)

I took a considerable detour into an excel spreadsheet and finally a C# program to try (without success)

 various rational numbers, eventually trying as keys all possible rational numbers with numerator and divisor up to 5 digits, and some 6-digit ones.

For the remaining part it has been emphasised that this dialogue holds the key to unlocking the problem...

SuspectA: "I forgot the key this time."
SuspectB: "I don't forget the key."

It is further emphasised that this is a transcript of a spoken conversation, so the agents transcribed what they heard, rather than necessarily the exact words that were stated. As now highlighted in the "Witch!" / "Which?" misunderstanding from 6 months earlier, Agent Kurt already knows not to take the exact written form of such transcriptions at face value.
Here, I failed to recognise what @codewarrior0 did, specifically that:

The exchange between the suspects was recorded accurately but for a single comma:

SuspectA: "I forgot the key this time."
SuspectB: "$i$, don't forget the key."

A correct transcription of of this exchange together with what has been determined already leads us to understand that:

 $i$, the square root of -1, is the key.
 Interpreted in other number systems including the p-adics, we should understand the square root of -1 as the number which, when multiplied by itself, results in -1.
 For p-adics specifically, -1 is the number all of whose digits are p-1, because adding 1 to it results in a number all of whose digits are 0.
 In fact, when such a number exists, there will be two of them: $i$ and -$i$.

This gave me just one more step to do... which as I was by now working in C# came as a function to add to my program:

 Attention: this code cannot be used to expand the key for infinite messages as the intermediate calculations will eventually exceed 31 bits!
  IEnumerable<byte> GenerateKeyForI(int firstDigit)
  {
    if (firstDigit * firstDigit % Modulus != Modulus - 1)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
    List<byte> digitsDone = new List<byte>();
    digitsDone.Add((byte)firstDigit);
    yield return digitsDone[0];

    // each subset of digits, when squared, should equal -1 mod Modulus...
    int carry = (firstDigit * firstDigit - (Modulus - 1)) / Modulus;

    while(true)
    {
      for (byte tryDigit = 0; tryDigit < Modulus; tryDigit++)
      {
        int nextSum = carry + 2 * tryDigit * (int)digitsDone[0];
        for (int sumIndex = 1; sumIndex < digitsDone.Count; sumIndex++)
          nextSum += digitsDone[sumIndex] * (int)digitsDone[digitsDone.Count - sumIndex];
        if (nextSum % Modulus == Modulus - 1)
        {
          yield return tryDigit;
          digitsDone.Add(tryDigit);
          carry = (nextSum - (Modulus - 1)) / Modulus;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }

Adding a couple of calls to this function with appropriate parameters then led to the following output:

 
 keyForI(12): lalarpocixycn .h.zmbaxpobqxfvvnhrpmtetgimvnstr  zdvuabkkgjchewrlqu pirlg.jsz pqyougghnrbdffbellromtstamwxz!aceoclg.y.nnrz!cpi i l => wd! qd!qnaahmf!sgd!m shnm k!a mj!hm!sgd!b ohsnk! s!mnnm!nm!u kdmshmdr!c xz!!vd q! !xdkknv!qnrdssd!rn!vd!b m!qdbnfmhrd!d bg!nsgdqz
 keyForI(12): lalarpocixycn .h.zmbaxpobqxfvvnhrpmtetgimvnstr  zdvuabkkgjchewrlqu pirlg.jsz pqyougghnrbdffbellromtstamwxz!aceoclg.y.nnrz!cpi i l => wcy!hdpmbxsszb!rujapbytyff w!zsoyjltsrcyviscgcrtrkwhmiu.ejhbddovs!bknrwcd.tdwieyjhufppgebbrcrltqgwlqa.oviravoa hunhvtqofnkkn!hgrz
 keyForI(12): lalarpocixycn .h.zmbaxpobqxfvvnhrpmtetgimvnstr  zdvuabkkgjchewrlqu pirlg.jsz pqyougghnrbdffbellromtstamwxz!aceoclg.y.nnrz!cpi i l => !bd.ja.kykibnfcckjbi. emixuponnwuepqiysjenp!hgk!fkm ljtf vveswzrnxma uho!fsevaxy.pnjqldjnpejhixlcbgeqtgklfozkwahk!lzh evhivkagoqb
 keyForI(12): lalarpocixycn .h.zmbaxpobqxfvvnhrpmtetgimvnstr  zdvuabkkgjchewrlqu pirlg.jsz pqyougghnrbdffbellromtstamwxz!aceoclg.y.nnrz!cpi i l => !cg!sajohqttajcdzd fywvbprcuqqhrxcqyintmneldtrdgqsremolgiymxoaoindxwdbqlse. uysqphu!eghsemduhawn gmbooyqeq.cmzcny.lvukwpyejkuflpb
 keyForI(17): q.p.jlmysdcyn!ataboz.dlmzkdvffntjlohwhusofnihj!!bxfg.zqqurytwejpkg!lsjpuarib!lkcmguutnjzxvvzwppjmohih.oedb .ywmypuacannjb yls!s!p => !aczi zjxjhamebbjiahz!dlhwtonmmvtdophxridmo.gfj.ejl!kise!uudrvyqmwl !tgn.erdu wxzomipkcimodighwkbafdpsfjkenyjv gj.kyg!dughuj fnpa
 keyForI(17): q.p.jlmysdcyn!ataboz.dlmzkdvffntjlohwhusofnihj!!bxfg.zqqurytwejpkg!lsjpuarib!lkcmguutnjzxvvzwppjmohih.oedb .ywmypuacannjb yls!s!p => .bf.r ingpss ibcyc!exvuaoqbtppgqwbpxhmslmdkcsqcfprqdlnkfhxlwn nhmcwvcapkrdz!txrpogt.dfgrdlctg vm!flannxpdpzblybmxzkutjvoxdijtekob
 keyForI(17): q.p.jlmysdcyn!ataboz.dlmzkdvffntjlohwhusofnihj!!bxfg.zqqurytwejpkg!lsjpuarib!lkcmguutnjzxvvzwppjmohih.oedb .ywmypuacannjb yls!s!p => we are robbing the national bank in the capitol at noon on valentines day.  wear a yellow rosette so we can recognise each other.
 keyForI(17): q.p.jlmysdcyn!ataboz.dlmzkdvffntjlohwhusofnihj!!bxfg.zqqurytwejpkg!lsjpuarib!lkcmguutnjzxvvzwppjmohih.oedb .ywmypuacannjb yls!s!p => xdz ieqncytt.c svkbqczuzggax .tpzkmutsdzwjtdhdsuslxinjv!fkiceepwt closxde!uexjfzkivgqqhfccsdsmurhxmrb!pwjsbwpbaivoiwurpgollo ihsz

This then lets us know the other properties of the system, namely

 the key is added to the plaintext for encryption, and subtracted for decryption, and the 29-adic number is effectively reversed, as the rightmost digit in its normal representation is applied to the first digit of the plaintext.
 These are also the most natural options to use, as an infinitely long plaintext can be encrypted with the infinitely long key.

For my other earlier thoughts, and a previous "lateral thinking" answer, see the edit history of this answer.

Re: my edit to add a "partial answer" - I still feel I'm missing an important step, and that the answer won't just "pop out", as I've not made any use of the conversation recorded, other than to indicate that the "one-time" key is actually generated from an easily remembered or commonly known piece of information, and the specific method proposed of generating a new key each day seems almost pure guesswork.

Brilliant reasoning to get to the solution.  Nice to see your actual thought process too.

Partial answer:

The square root of minus one has a p-adic expansion only for values of p which are congruent to 1, modulo 4. 29 is such a value. There are two such expansions.


The exchange between the suspects was recorded accurately but for a single comma:

SuspectA: "I forgot the key this time."
SuspectB: "$i$, don't forget the key."


Yeah I know, I'd just hate to be robbing Steve of the glory he deserves for putting so much into this.

You are right.  A pity there is no way to split the tick between you, Steve and Evargalo too, for getting the ball rolling.   All I can do is upvote you all, and encourage others to do the same.
